# computational complexity of an expression

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

I am wondering what is the time complexity of the following expression:

[image]

where `A`  and `Y`  are `n×n`  sparse matrices with `nnz`  non-zeros, and `x`  and `y`  are `n×1`  vectors.

I found `(A*A*A)*x` would be more efficient if we compute it as `A*(A*(A*x))`. So is there some memorization techniques I can use to efficiently compute this expression?

Comment: Two questions, 1st why do you think that computing `A*(A*(A*x))` is more efficient than `(A*A*A)*x`? And what do you want to memorize in this scenario?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: A*(A*(A*x)) is 3 times multiplying matrix with vector, while (A*A*A)*x is multiplying matrices twice and then multiplying matrix with vector. Theoretically - there are much less ops in Matrix*vector then in Matrix*Matrix.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, maybe memorize `y^T * Y`